# Parsing files with county codes

Tags: python, optimization, parsing, csv

I am running through a file and inserting elements one by one. The counties all contain specific county codes which are duplicated many times throughout the file. I am looking for a way to assign these codes to a specific county while ignoring duplicate county codes.

I have two versions I wrote below with runtimes:

**`getCodes()`**

```
def get_codes(data):
    code_info = {}
    for row in data:
        county = row["county"]
        code = int(float(row["code"]))
        if code > 100000:
            code = code/100
        if county not in code_info:
            code_info[county] = []
        code_info[county].append(code)
    for county in code_info:
        code_info[county] = list(set(code_info[county]))
    return code_info
```

**`get_codes2()`**

```
def get_codes2(data):
    code_info = {}
    for row in data:
        county = row["county"]
        code = int(float(row["code"]))
        if code > 100000:
            code = code/100

        if county in code_info:
            if not code in code_info[county]:
                code_info[county].append(code)
        else:
            code_info[county] = []
            code_info[county].append(code)
    return code_info
```

```
county_data = csv.DictReader(open("county_file.txt"))
start = time.time()
county_codes = get_codes(county_data)
end = time.time()
print "run time: " + str(end-start)

county_data = csv.DictReader(open("county_file.txt"))
start = time.time()
county_codes = get_codes2(county_data)
end = time.time()
print "run time: " + str(end-start)
```

Also, it's probably obvious from this, but county codes that are greater than 100000 can have trailing zeroes accidentally added, so I'm removing them by dividing by 100. As another note, the `int(float())` conversion is intentional. Sometimes the county codes are values such as "27.7" and need to be converted to "27", other times they are just basic `int`s.

The runtimes on my system:

- `get_codes`: 9 seconds
- `get_codes2`: 14 seconds

How can I improve this further for better performance?

Comment: Python 2.5 supports a [`defaultdict`](http://blog.ludovf.net/python-collections-defaultdict/), which might save some time with the "if county in code_info" checks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close to optimal here. I made a few tweaks, to avoid some conditionals by using sets instead. I don't actually know if it'll run faster; you'll need to benchmark it, and it likely depends on the breakdown of how many dupes per county there are.

```
def get_codes3(data):
    from collections import defaultdict
    codeinfo = defaultdict(set)
    for row in data:
        county = row["county"]
        # remove float() if you can get away with it - are there
        # actually values like '1.5' in the data?
        code = int(float(row["code"]))
        if code > 100000:
            code = code/100

        codeinfo[county].add(code)
    # if you can get away with sets instead of lists in your return
    # value, you're good
    return code_info
    # otherwise:
    # return dict([(county, list(info)) for county, info in code_info.iteritems()])
```

- You don't need `float()` unless the data is actually like `"123.45"` - it's not clear if that's the case
- `set`s can work in most places that lists work, so you might not need to convert to a list
- It might be worth it to write a script that does just the `x = x/100 if x > 100000` part and writes that out to a new file

Comment: I ran a few bench marks, the time difference was negligible (usually within a few hundredth of a second).

To respond to a few of your questions:
1. Yes, I need int(float()) there. There are some values like "123.45" that need to be converted to "123", but most are already integers. You are definitely right though, I should have mentioned this in my original post
2. Yeah, I

Comment: 2. You may be correct on the set issue, but I need to access the data structure by index later on, so I'd prefer to convert it to a list. 3. That would be ideal solution, but the data in the file may change but the format issue won't. You solution looks a lot more elegant than mine though!

Comment: @MikeJ, if you ran AdamKG's exact code for your benchmark, you should try it again with the import moved outside of the function. As I understand imports are actually pretty expensive. Also, try dropping the square brackets for the alternate return. There's not much reason to generate a list first.

Comment: Additionally, you could write `code = code / 100` as `code /= 100` if you're going for brevity. It doesn't do much for performance, but it's quicker to read.